# static variable generating : non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context error

Tags: java, static, jdialog

I am at a loss here.

I can see any reason that why the following is happening :

```
        public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
            .
            .
            .
            .
377:        private static JDialog dialog;
378:
379:        static void conflict_dialog(){
380:        dialog =  new conflict(this, true,new File("C:\\Users\\Soumya\\Desktop\\a.sh"), 2242);
381:        dialog.setVisible(send_mode);
            .
            .

            }

        }
```

> Uncompilable source code - non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context at new_file_transfer.UI.conflict_dialog(UI.java:380)

any ideas on why I am getting this error will be very helpful

Comment: this is an instance of class,a non static member.you cant reference non static from static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
dialog =  new conflict(this, ...);
```

You're in a static method - what do you expect `this` to be? It *could* be appropriate to construct a new `UI` as per thinksteep's answer - or you may want to use an existing reference from somewhere else. It's hard to say for sure. When you wrote that code, what did you *want* `this` to refer to?

(Note that to follow Java naming conventions, your `conflict` class should be renamed to `Conflict`; your method should probably be renamed to `showConflictDialog` and your `send_mode` variable should probably be `sendMode`.)

Comment: no I don't need it to refer to **this**. **new UI()** should have been my work fine  (i just want to inherit the look&feel)

Comment: and thanks for the pointer on the naming convention. I'm correcting those (and a several others)right now.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a reference to an instance of an object with `this` inside of a static method- which doesn't have a `this`.

You need to either create a new instance of `UI` inside the call:
`dialog = new conflict(New UI(), true, ...);`

or change the method to be non-static and call it from an instance of `UI`.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `this` use `new UI()` in

```
dialog =  new conflict(this, true,new File("C:\\Users\\Soumya\\Desktop\\a.sh"), 2242);
```

(or)

Remove static from `static void conflict_dialog(){`

Because "conflict_dialog" is static (class scope), you can't access instance scope (`this`).

Comment: conflict_dialog() has to be static 
but thanks for pointing out about 'this' 
I totally missed that

Comment: @Soumyaxyz: If so, the only option you have may be using new UI(), but as Jon Skeet said, with out full context it is hard to tell correct solution.

Comment: no **new UI()** will work perfectly(just want to inherit the look&feel)

Answer (score 0):

Static methods execute when the class loads first time in a program.

To access static method or variable there is no need of object

```
  'ClassName.mystaticethod();'
```

here we haven't created any object.

And      'this' refers to the current object using which we are calling method or variable.

Even without creating any object we can access static methods.

So in the case of static methods "this" doesn't have any meaning. Because there is no object created , So there is no "this" (Current object).